# split string of 8 characters in for loop in php

Tags: php

I have strings (checked with gettype) from 8 characters like this:

```
47780000
79110000
96040000
49321200
```

My goal is to split each string in 4 parts, and each part should have length of 2 characters

Here is my code:

```
    foreach($klist as $k){
        echo $kad ."<br />";
        $part1 = trim(substr($k,0,2));
        echo $part1 ."<br />";
        $part2 = trim(substr($k,2,2));
        echo $part2 ."<br />";
        $part3 = trim(substr($k,4,2));
        echo $part3 ."<br />";
        $part4 = trim(substr($k,6,2));
        echo $part4 ."<br />";
    }
```

Here is the output that I get:

```
47780000
47
78
00
00
// above output is correct and as I want it to be

// however, the results bellow are wrong, there is one character missing

79110000
7
91
10
00

96040000
9
60
40
00

49321200
4
93
21
20
```

Can anyone help me with this code and explain to me why I have one character less in each result after the first result?

Comment: You should have trimmed (once) before substr()ing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `chunk_split()` for Splits a string into a series of smaller parts

```
Example:
      echo chunk_split('96040000', 2, "<br>");
```

Solution for your problem:

```
   $klist = [47780000, 79110000, 96040000, 49321200];
   foreach($klist as $k){
        echo chunk_split($k, 2, "<br>")."<br>";
   }
```

Output:

```
47
78
00
00

79
11
00
00

96
04
00
00

49
32
12
00
```

Comment: If you place this code in a for loop, it produces exactly same output as in my question, so it does not work.

Comment: @user2417624 Is this resolve your problem?. or do you want to display number before the split?

Comment: Your code does work, however there is something in the array that I get which cause this issue. And I have to find out how to clear my input...

Comment: `echo chunk_split(trim($k), 2, "<br>")."<br>";`

Comment: @Dark Bee , the trim that you add in the Shivudra code did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol that you don't see, but it is used is a **linebreak**. Remove it.

I don't know how you create `$klist`, but with `file` - use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` as a second argument. Or apply `trim` to every string before processing.

Comment: As you can see in my question, I already have trim. I will check if file_ignore_new_lines can do the trick.

Comment: You have `trim` __after__ selecting substring. Original value `$k` should be trimmed first.

Comment: @user2417624 trim will only take effect once the `substr` has taken place, and if there are new lines as part of that substring, then they are being included.  It seems likely that the value `$k` has line breaks in it, or other 'invisible' characters which are counted as part of `substr`.  You'll need to remove these form `$k`

Comment: You are right about the linebreak, but I can not find the way to remove it yet

Comment: `$k = trim($k);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$klist = [47780000,
79110000,
96040000,
49321200];
$kad = PHP_EOL;

 foreach($klist as $k){
        echo $kad ."<br />";
        $part1 = trim(substr($k,0,2));
        echo $part1 ."<br />";
        $part2 = trim(substr($k,2,2));
        echo $part2 ."<br />";
        $part3 = trim(substr($k,4,2));
        echo $part3 ."<br />";
        $part4 = trim(substr($k,6,2));
        echo $part4 ."<br />";
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
<br />47<br />78<br />00<br />00<br />
<br />79<br />11<br />00<br />00<br />
<br />96<br />04<br />00<br />00<br />
<br />49<br />32<br />12<br />00<br />
```